# How can I smooth a graph with hundreds of points?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with data from my Spotify account and I've created a dataframe that contains all the minutes in the day and the total playtime during that minute for the last 5 years. The dataframe is this (by the way, I wonder if there is any way to work with time without having to select a specific date):

```
                    time   playtime
0    1970-01-01 00:00:00  47.138733
1    1970-01-01 00:01:00  52.419767
2    1970-01-01 00:02:00  47.943567
3    1970-01-01 00:03:00  43.322283
4    1970-01-01 00:04:00  58.029217
...                  ...        ...
1435 1970-01-01 23:55:00  46.276150
1436 1970-01-01 23:56:00  53.202717
1437 1970-01-01 23:57:00  49.844367
1438 1970-01-01 23:58:00  62.703600
1439 1970-01-01 23:59:00  55.437700
```

I've plotted the dataframe in order to obtain a visualization of how much music I listen during the day. This is the graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNIkU.png)

There are 1440 points, so outliers will appear. But, as you can probably see, there is a smooth curve that emerges from the graph. I want to get the actual smooth graph, but every method that I see uses interpolation and I don't think interpolating 1440 points is efficient. Is there any way to get a moving average or something similar so that I can plot a smooth curve?

I've tried interpolating, but there are too many points and it takes ages to run.

Answer (score 0):

[moving average](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-calculate-moving-average-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)

for averaging the last 30 records

```
df['playtime_rolling_30'] = df['playtime'].rolling(30).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For technical analysis and finance:

It is more convenient to use a reliable third-party package like [TA-Lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib). A simple moving average  operation with period of 3 then would be as simple as `talib.SMA(arr, 3)`.

#### For the purpose of education:

Here is a simple code for simple moving average:

```
def sma(arr, n=3):
    """
    total number of items to aveage over for each new element=2*n+1
    """
    res = np.array([])
    for sn, elem in enumerate(arr):
        ind_start=max(0, min(sn, sn-n))
        ind_end=min(len(arr), max(sn, sn+n))
        res = np.append(res, np.sum(arr[ind_start:ind_end]).astype('float32')/(ind_end-ind_start))
        
    return res

num_points=100
mu=0.
sig=3.
a=np.arange(num_points) + np.random.normal(mu, sig, num_points)

sma_level = 3
plt.plot(a, label="raw")
plt.plot(sma(a, n=sma_level), '--', label=f"sma-{2*sma_level+1}")
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]